# Print correlation values on console in gatling

Tags: console, gatling

How can we print the values captured using `saveAs("myValue")` on the console of `gatling`, like we do `System.out.println()` in Java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Values saved with saveAs, are saved into session : 
Docs : http://gatling.io/docs/2.2.0/session/session_api.html#id2

Those values are actually logged into console automatically if you turn logging on in settings: resources/logback.xml 
uncomment :

```
<logger name="io.gatling.http.ahc" level="TRACE" /> 
<logger name="io.gatling.http.response" level="TRACE" />
```

With this settings you will see this before each reqest:

`Session:
Session(<Session desc.>,5846298469383031361-23,Map(<session vars>),1463134760217,8,KO,List(),<function1>)`

Or you have to print your vars in session function:

```
val printSesssionVar = scenario("print session var").exec{
    session =>
      println(session("<your session var>").as[String])
      session
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

umm good to know. I thought we had to use always brackets after .exec

```
  val printSesssionVar = scenario("print session var")
    .exec(session => {
      val mySesionVariable = session("your session var").as[String]
      println(mySesionVariable)
      session
    })
```