# Print gatling session map values on console

Tags: scala, console, gatling

I am fairly new to gatling, and I am trying to print out Map values of session to the console. The values saved in the session are of the format.

```
sessionVariable -> Map (key1 -> Map(nkey1 -> nval1, nkey2 -> nval2 ...), key2 -> val2, key3 -> val3)
```

I am trying to get the `val2` or even `nval1` from the session variable.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37175459/print-correlation-values-on-console-in-gatling) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49872999/gatling-how-to-access-individual-values-in-session-arrays), I see I could do something like

```
val printSesssionVar = scenario("print session var").exec{
    session =>
      println(session("<your session var>").as[String])
      session
  }
.
```

So I have tried

```
 val printSesssionVar = scenario("print session var").exec{
    session =>
      println(session("sessionVariable(2)").as[String])
      println(session("sessionVariable[2]").as[String])
      println(session("${sessionVariable[2]}").as[String])
      println(session("${sessionVariable.key2}").as[String])
      session
  }
```

From the [documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/session/expression_el/), it is proper to use something like ${sessionVariable.key2} in a method, but I want to print the results to console.

but none seem to work. Please any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found a way; that is, getting the variable from the session not as a string but as a Map which is the right format of the data returned.

```
val printSesssionVar = scenario("print session var").exec{
    session =>
      val varFromSession = session("sessionVariable(0)").as[Map[String, Any]])
      println(varFromSession("key2"))
      session
  }
```

Comment: It's not a workaround. It's the correct way to do it with Gatling's Scala DSL.

Comment: thanks @StéphaneLANDELLE, I'm fairly new to scala too.

Comment: Then, we have a Java API coming for you (next week or the week after).

Comment: really? Yay ! :)